# 400 Error Code while using RestTemplate for a Rest API

Tags: java, rest, postman, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I have a REST API to call and I have written the client using rest template. When executing, I am getting 400 status code. The same REST API is working fine when using POSTMAN. Below are the code snippets for API and caller. Do let me know if anyone catches anything.

REST API for POST method-

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Download repository as zip")
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = ""), @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "")})
    @PostMapping(value = "/download", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadRepository(
            @RequestBody @Validated final RepositoriesRequest repositoriesRequest) {

        final Situation situation = this.situationsService.getSituationId(repositoriesRequest);
        if (isNull(situation)) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } else {
            final ExtractionRequest extractionRequest = new ExtractionRequest(repositoriesRequest.getType(), situation,
                    repositoriesRequest.getDatabase());

            if (!this.validateRequest(extractionRequest)) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
            }
            final ExtractionResponse response = this.extractService.extractRepository(extractionRequest);

            if (null == response) {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }
            final InputStream inputStream = this.extractService.getFileFromS3(response.getRepositoryPath());

            if (null == inputStream) {
                return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
            }

            final StreamingResponseBody bodyWriter = this.bodyWriter(inputStream);

            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/zip")
                    .header(CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"repository-" + situation.getId() + ".zip\"")
                    .body(bodyWriter);
        }
    }
```

REST CLIENT using Rest Template with auth token and request body as input -

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> buildLoadRepoRequest(
            final SimulationContext context,
            final List<String> tablesName,
            final String simulationId,
            final Integer offset) {
        final Token token = this.authenticateOkoye(simulationId, offset);
        LOGGER.info("Token Run: {}", token.getAccessToken());
        final String database = this.getDatabaseForEnvironment();

        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        httpHeaders.set(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token.getAccessToken());

        final MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("database", database);
        body.add("monthlyClosingMonth", context.getMonthlyClosingDate());
        body.add("repositorySnapshot", context.getRepository());
        body.add("situationId", context.getSituationId());
        body.add("tableNames", tablesName);
        body.add("type", context.getRunType());

        return new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders);
    }
```

Exception Handler -

```
    @Override
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
    public void loadRepository(
            final SimulationContext context,
            final List<String> tablesName,
            final String simulationId,
            final Integer offset,
            final Path repositoryPath) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("[{}] [{}] repository tablesName: {}", simulationId, offset, tablesName);
        this.restTemplate.setRequestFactory(this.getClientHttpRequestFactory());
        final ClientHttpResponse response = this.restTemplate.postForObject(
                this.repositoriesUrl,
                this.buildLoadRepoRequest(context, tablesName, simulationId, offset),
                ClientHttpResponse.class);

        if (response != null && HttpStatus.OK == response.getStatusCode()) {
            LOGGER.info(
                    "response status on simulation : {}  - Context: {} - status: {}",
                    simulationId,
                    offset,
                    response.getStatusCode());
            //this.helper.copy(response.getBody(), repositoryPath);
        } else if (response != null && HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT != response.getStatusCode()) {
            throw new JarvisException(
                    "Can't retrieve RWA repository on simulation " + simulationId + " Context:" + offset);
        }
    }
```

We have been looking into this issue since yesterday and still don't have any clue. So far we have tried postForEntity, exchange, changing the headers to proper setter methods and tried passing the parameters as an object also. None of them worked.

I have a strong feeling about something being wrong at header level while calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Or add consumes to @PostMapping annotation with APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 value